# How to remove instance of accumulo?

Tags: accumulo

I have created a instance while initializing accumulo by calling **accumulo init**
But now i want to remove that instance and as well i want to create a new instance.
Can any one help to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the directory specified by the instance.dfs.dir property in $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/accumulo-site.xml from HDFS.

If you did not specify an instance.dfs.dir in accumulo-site.xml, the default is "/accumulo".

You should then be able to call `accumulo init` with success.

Comment: Thanks for reply.... ya its working. Now i am able to create a new instance but when i am checking status(by using http://9.182.77.14:50095/) it showing instance name is null and id is also different one,not the new one.Can you plz tell how to solve this issue??

Comment: Just refresh the page. There's some (bad) static members in the monitor that aren't initialized correctly the first time you visit the page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to answer your follow-up comment.

Make sure you restarted the monitor process since reiniting. Furthermore, make sure the node you're running your monitor on has the same configuration as the rest of the instance, as well as the same configuration for Hadoop on the classpath based on HADOOP_HOME.

Comment: can you please tell how to restart monitor process?
I tried to stop all the processes by using /bin/stop-all.sh but that is not working.

Comment: find the process with ps/jps and just kill it. The only really stateful things are the tservers and that's why we have log recovery.